# The requested URL was not found on this server after upgrading

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was using MAMP 3.5.2 for my WordPress websites and it was working beautifully by using http://localhost:8888/WPfoldername

I installed MAMP 4.0.6, upgraded dbs to MySQL 5.6, etc.

Now when I try http://localhost:8888/WPfoldername I get:

> The requested URL /WPfoldername was not found on this server.

When going to my WebStart page, it also shows twice:

> MySQL can be administered with phpMyAdmin

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm getting views but no answers...do I need to give more information?  Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution here: http://haizdesign.com/mamp/updating-mamp-pro-4/  -  I moved the folders from my Sites folder to the MAMP/htdocs folder and all are working again!  Hope this helps someone else.